# how to fix SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request

Tags: android, android-webservice

I sync data from webservice using SOAP(ksoap2) lib.Early days my application is everything ok. Today, when I run my program today, I get the following error at this line **SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();**

```
  private final static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

private static String URL = "http://172.230.0.30/pos_cashsale/Service1.asmx";
private final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";
  public static String invokeJSONWS(String Name1, String Value1,
        String Name2, String Value2, String methName) {
    String responseJSON = "";
    // Create request
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methName);

        if (!Value1.equals("")) {
            // Property which holds input parameters
            PropertyInfo paramPI = new PropertyInfo();
            // Set Name
            paramPI.setName(Name1);
            // Set Value
            paramPI.setValue(Value1);
            // Set dataType
            paramPI.setType(String.class);
            // Add the property to request object
            request.addProperty(paramPI);
        }

        if (!Value2.equals("")) {
            // Property which holds input parameters
            PropertyInfo paramPI2 = new PropertyInfo();

            // Set Name
            paramPI2.setName(Name2);
            // Set Value
            paramPI2.setValue(Value2);
            // Set dataType
            paramPI2.setType(String.class);
            // Add the property to request object
            request.addProperty(paramPI2);
        }

        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER10);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + methName, envelope);
            // Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            // Assign it to static variable
            responseJSON = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseJSON;
}
```

[image]